# Common library framework for iOS, watchOS, tvOS and macOS

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, tvos, watchos

I'm a framework developer, developed a library sometime back to be used for iOS applications.

Now I'm updating the library to use swift package manager and my intention is this library is to be used across all platforms, iOS, watchOS, tvOS and macOS. This library is utility based and not tied to any features of a specific platform so can be used across devices.

What threw me off is different projects within XCode mentioned under Frameworks and Library. I'm attaching some screenshots for reference.

The question, can this library be used across these different projects or do I've a to create a separate Framework for each device?

```
iOS-> Cocoa Touch Framework
watchOS -> Watch Framework
tvOS -> TV Framework
macOS -> Cocoa Framework
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you will have to create separate targets for each platform that your framework should support. You will then be able to conditionally link possible other frameworks used by your code to these targets. In code you can use #if os(iOS)... to differ between platforms, but according to your question that's not necessary. However, I think you will have to ship different binaries for the different platforms, a single file for all won't work.

Comment: Thanks Flo. Different targets and same source files, I think I did try that path and was disgusted by all those extra folders getting created in my project for each target.